# onmouseover with css not working

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to add an image with a mouseovereffect, but my current effort doesn't display anything. So there's no image to be seen. I've tested the image path and that is correct: with in my view `image_tag(icons/admin.png)` it displays the image. What am I doing wrong?

View (there's no text nor a link, which is why I'm using `"", ""`, but also with only one `""` the image still doesn't display):

```
<td><%= link_to("", "", title: "admin", class: "is-admin") if user_type_1? %></td>
# Also tried it without the if part, just to be sure, but I'm certain that part is true.
```

CSS:

```
.is-admin {
  background-image: image-url('icons/admin.png');
}
.is-admin:hover {
  background-image: image-url('icons/admin_2.png');
}
```

**Update**: I turns out there is a sizing issue: it displays the images with size 0. So I've added to the CSS:

```
.sizing {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

And in my view:

```
<td><%= link_to("", "", title: "admin", class: "sizing is-admin") %></td>
```

Then if I look in the inspector the size of the images still shows 0, while the inspector for their css confirms the specification of 15x15. I've not seen that before: that using Firefox's inspector and you move over an element it gives one size while if you've selected the element in the css on the right of the screen, it gives you a different size.

Comment: Try to use just `background-image: url('icons/admin.png');` not `image-url`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: Is the non-hovered image working? Because I may have an idea how to fix that.

Comment: No, there's no image at all. There's only an image if I don't use css and in my view use `image_tag(icons/admin.png)` instead. The other css in the stylesheet works, so that's not the cause either.

Comment: Isolate the problem by testing if mouseovereffect is triggered by changing a different CSS attribute such as background-color.

Comment: Tried it, added background-color for mouseover. Moved the mouse over where I would expect the image to show up, but nothing happens. It simply doesn't seem to display the entire table column with the image.

Comment: Are you sure that your css file is loaded correctly? Are other styles working?

Comment: Yes, the other styles work. I now also tried `<td style="background-color: #...">` and it then does show the column but without content/the image.

Comment: Your first `""` decides what's inside your `<a>HERE</a>`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, I found the solution. Using the following `.sizing` in the CSS solved it:

```
display: inline-block; 
background-size: cover;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your css property value from `image-url` to `url` should work after that.

#### EDIT

Try defining your background image with the

```
display: block;
```

Property.

Comment: Kay. Didn't see the comment.

Comment: I added `display: block;` to the css `is-admin` and `is-admin:hover` styles, but that made no difference.

Comment: Would changing your class name from .is-admin to .is_admin work?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help

Comment: With your update you tried width and height, how about adding background-size: 15px; not able to run ruby with my phone so I could only think about the outcome. My apologies for any misleading information.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that also made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with nothing inside your `td`, try to add `&nbsp;`.
If I understand your code correctly, it should looks like this:

```
<td><%= link_to("&nbsp;", "#", title: "admin", class: "is-admin") if user_type_1? %></td>
```

which will result in

```
<td><a title="admin" class="is_admin" href="#">&nbsp;</a></td>
```

and then your styles should start to work.

Comment: If I do that than it displays `&nbsp` and when I move my mouse over that text it changes color. But the images are still not displayed. Or better said, they have a size of 0 (See update added to the post).

Comment: What about `&nbsp\\` Does it make any difference?